# Save POST data to exception context in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, post, laravel-9

So I'm adding some data to my exceptions that get logged in my Laravel 9 application by overriding the `context()` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

I tried to add POST data by doing the following:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $context['post'] = $_POST;
}
```

But this does not work because $_POST is always empty. If I had access to the `$request` I could get it from there, but I can't access it from here as far as I can tell.

I wasn't aware that post data wasn't saved in $_POST like I would have expected in Laravel. Is there any way to access this data to include it in the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the [`\request()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-request) method?

```php
    if (count($post = \request()->post())) {
        $context['post'] = $post;
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't even realize this method exists, thanks!